# How can i differentiate between the declared variables with the same rule but in different scope (ANTLR 4)?

Tags: java, antlr4

I am developing my own language with ANTLR 4, here is a part of my grammar.

```
program: main EOF;  // the program rule. 
main:  NEWLINE* study  NEWLINE* ; // the main rule;
study : studyBlock (NEWLINE* assignVariableBlock)? ;  // the study rule.
/* simple assign name = "name" */
simpleAssign: name = ID  '=' value = (STRING | BOOLEAN | INTEGER | DOUBLE);
/* study parameters */
studyParameters: (| ( simpleAssign (',' simpleAssign)*) );
/* study block */
studyBlock: 'study' '(' studyParameters  ')' NEWLINE ;
/* assign variables block */
assignVariableBlock: simpleAssign*;
```

The simpleAssign rule is used in the rule studyParameters and in the rule assignVariableBlock ,so how can I get the variables declared in each specific block.For example if my DSL is as follows.

```
study(string = "string", string2 = "string2")

x = "string3"
y = "string4"
```

How can I have in my listener

```
// study parameters
[string:"string",string2:"string2"] // map 
// tmp variabels
[x:"string3",y:"string4"] // map
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inspect the context's `parent` variable:

```java
@Override 
public void enterSimpleAssign(YourParser.SimpleAssignContext ctx) { 
  if (ctx.parent instanceof YourParser.StudyParametersContext) {
    // called from `studyParameters`
  }
  else {
    // called from `assignVariableBlock`
  }
}
```